# Java: skip binary data in xml file while parsing

Tags: java, xml, parsing, binary

I want to parse a xml file in java which contains binary data: here is an example of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<documents>
  <document>
    <element name="docid">
      <value><![CDATA[0902307e8004c74c]]></value>
    </element>
    <element name="published">
      <value><![CDATA[2012-01-01T00:00:00]]></value>
    </element>
    <element name="documenttype">
      <value><![CDATA[Circular]]></value>
    </element>
    <element name="data">
      <value><![CDATA[%PDF-1.6
%����
1020 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 20/Length 270/N 3/Type/ObjStm>>stream
�o^���)|�,�Ypoef�
l���o�>����u���b"Cb�|���%&��D�yD��q�q�q�q�q��%_ja�LJob��/��3"=����o���]V11}�    }a�+'6@����C�,^}�d%�۠�`s��q��5�׷^(�N��{S<S�����A��������-������f\ڌ��|U/݌�z���f�I9����g�g���s���0z'��X~
endstream
endobj
startxref
55097
%%EOF
]]></value>
    </element>
    <element name="dataname">
      <value><![CDATA[sdfsfsfsdsdfsd.pdf]]></value>
    </element>
  </document>
</documents>
```

Normally I would parse such an xml file that way:

```
Document doc = null;
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = null;
documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
try {

            doc = documentBuilder.parse(fastXMLFile);

        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("SAXExept");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Test");
            return;
        }
```

But because of the "data" element which contains binary data, the debugger tells me:

```
[Fatal Error] xmlfile.xml:58:10: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1a) was found in the CDATA section.
SAXExept
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1a) was found in the CDATA section.
```

I dont need to parse this data field by now, I could just skip it. I just want to parse the rest of the data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your XML includes invalid characters (as the exception shows), you can't expect libraries to parse it successfully. Since you can't change the XML file creation process, and since you can't see the code of the search engine, I believe the easiest for you will be to remove the Invalid characters from the XML.

so the process would be:

1- read the contents of the XML into a String

2- parse the String and remove all Invalid Charachters

3- write the String back into the file. or create a new file if you can't modify the original

4- parse the modified/new file.

In order to replace invalid characters, see the following link as it also includes a method to do so.

[Invalid XML Characters: when valid UTF8 does not mean valid XML](http://blog.mark-mclaren.info/2007/02/invalid-xml-characters-when-valid-utf8_5873.html).

Comment: I think this could work for now but I cant imagine that this is the final solution. Our search engine also has to parse this data somehow....for my problem I do not really need to parse the binary data so I cut cut it out but it would really interest me how to handle it differntly.
When I open the xml in Notepad++ it recognizes all nodes of the xml. Some parts of the xml file arent correctly displayed...so the text is gray... but all nodes are correct. That means the actual structure of my xml file is also correct. So I do not know why it should not be possible to parse the whole thing.

Comment: And how can I convert the XML to a String when I am not able to read the xml?

Comment: Becuase there are standards for parsing XML documents and they allow such case. If you want to write your own parser which does not follow the standard and deals with exceptional cases, you can do so. that is actually what happens with your search engine most probably. notepad++ does not parse your xml. the structure is correct so you see nodes correctly but there is no parsing.

Comment: read it not through xml parser but just as you read a text file.

Comment: I did as you told me and it works fine. Thank you very much for this. And if someone finds an answer how to keep the binary data alive, it would be a big pleasure but for now this solution is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You XML document is invalid.
PDF data should be base64 encoded or HEX.
I don't think there is a solution except changing your document.

Regards

Comment: The problem is, that this document is created by an internat program for our search engine. I cant change anything.
An ok I skipped something of the binary data...maybe that confused you. Isnt there any solution?

Comment: It must be possible somehow because our search engine is able to parse such xml files, but of cource I cant get the code for that. I just want to write my own parsing. I could also see that when I copy the xml file on the top that this file is wrong but I cant paste the whole xml document because it contains in-company data that I cant share.